# Windows won't release lock on drive tray after burning a disc

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

I have two bluray drives of the same exact model and brand installed in my computer. I occasionally like to use either of them to burn CDs or DVDs using various software (Windows Media Player 12, Zune, ImgBurn, Windows DVD Maker, etc). It will get through the burning process and complete successfully, but with either drive, it will not release the resource lock on the disc, meaning the disc continues to spin, the access light flashes continuously, and I cannot eject the drive. When I use ImgBurn to burn a disc, it will typically do a verify step after burning, which cycles the drive tray. Because the lock is not released, it will not be able to cycle the drive tray. Right now, I've just burned a CD in Windows Media Player, and it completed successfully (I can even play the CD in WMP) but I cannot eject the drive. The only reliable way I've found of getting the disc out is to reboot the machine and then when it powers back up I can eject the disc.

Why would this be happening? It's consistently doing this 100% of the time. I've updated my drivers but it didn't change anything.

This is the specific drive listing on TigerDirect: [Lite-On iHBS212-08 12X Internal Blu-Ray Writer](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6577321)

I'm using Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1.

Has anyone run into this kind of issue before? What can I do to fix it?

**EDIT**

Note, I also just updated the firmware for the drives, which didn't help. Additionally, I unplugged one of them (on the off chance that the fact that there were 2 identical drives was causing conflicts somewhere) and it made no difference.

Also, I found a way to force the ability to get the drive tray open without rebooting. Through ImgBurn, I went to the Tools menu, then Drive, then clicked "Close session" and it let me open the tray again.

Also of note, if I instead tried clicking "Eject" in the Drive menu in ImgBurn, it gave me a descriptive error message, basically stating lots of technical junk and the error "Logical unit not ready - Long write in progress". I think this long write is what's keeping the drive occupied. But it doesn't appear to ever finish. So is this a driver issue then? It does happen across programs.

**EDIT #2**

Per Paperlantern's suggestion below, I tried using a Linux LiveCD session to burn a disc. I booted into Kubuntu and burned a small audio CD using k3b. Interestingly, it worked perfectly. It burned the CD and then ejected the disc at the end. So this apparently is not a hardware issue, but a Windows one.

**EDIT #3**

After some troubleshooting with the help of a couple people here, I've determined that the likely cause is a problem with how Windows is issuing commands to ATAPI devices. This Windows installation originally was installed to an IDE drive, but it was switched over to RAID without doing a reinstall. This may have put Windows in a state where it isn't properly communicating with the drives. I did a fresh install of Windows on the machine (after backing up my previous installation) and did a couple test burns and Windows operates properly, ejecting the drive at the end of the burn job. I will restore my backup image and proceed from there.

Comment: It sounds like a driver/OS issue. Is there a way to view what process is locking the drive?

Comment: @soandos I know which program initiates the lock. It's always the one that I am using to burn the drive, whether it be Windows Media Player, ImgBurn, or something else. I don't believe that there's an intermediary process that one of these communicates with to burn the disc, is there?

Comment: No idea, but perhaps worth a check?

Comment: @soandos Well I wouldn't know how to check for that. My hunch is that it's not the case though, if that means anything...

Comment: have you tried using different types of disks? The author of imageburn seems fond of vertabim  http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=11705 http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=9484

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I haven't tried those (I'm using Memorex discs) and I have no idea why it would make a difference but I'll give it a go. It is a Lite-On drive and they make discs too so I'll try those.

Comment: If you kill the process that's burning, does the drive get unlocked then? (just investigating)

Comment: @Karel Even if I exit the program it will not release the drive tray. The resource is locked on an OS level (it seems) and just never gets unlocked.

Comment: "Logical unit not ready - Long write in progress" -> that looks like an 'infinite loop' in the driver. Maybe you found a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this happens on any and all types of burns? To alleviate ANY issues with current driver or software being the problem, what I would do, being as frustrated as you probably are, is to load a copy of linux mint or ubuntu linux onto a spare drive in the machine. Or use the live CD in one drive and try to burn something on the other drive, to see if the problem occurs in another OS and software environment altogether. It could at least tell us if the problem is the hardware (maybe bad batch of CD ROM drives with messed up cache or something equally bizarre?), or if the issue resides with your OS or driver in some way.

If it is OS related, running a sysprep on the machine would force a redetect and reinstall of the key components involved (CDROM drivers and the ATAPI interface software), and will most likely solve this issue since a new install worked.

Comment: Yes it does, as far as I know. I've tested it lately with music CDs but burning video DVDs have reproduced the same situation. That's a good idea. Unfortunately my previous attempts to load Ubuntu using Wubi were met with errors. I'll see if a LiveCD is good enough, though.

Comment: Another option might be pendrivelinux, basically a bootable USB stick of the live cd of really almost any distro under the sun. I use it extensively for troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, I was able to get into a Kubuntu LiveCD and tried burning an audio CD using k3b, and it worked. It was only a single track, but it burned it quickly, and ejected the disc at the end. So it appears that it's a Windows issue, and not a hardware problem. I'll add this info to the main question, too.

Comment: Okay, now we at least know that if we try drivers or OS troubleshooting, we aren't wasting our time with a hardware problem. If you pull up hardware manager and expand DVD/CD-ROM drives, do the drives list properly. ie, drives listed, are the models installed. Additionally, if they are, when was the driver released? Does it show who made it? Is it maybe using a MS driver where in we could then swap in the mfr driver, or vice versa? Perhaps even trying a right click and "update driver software" could yield a newer driver. Perhaps attempting to remove them and reboot to redetect them may help.

Comment: I checked this and they are Microsoft drivers (and the latest ones available), and the devices are installed properly. I'll look at installing a manufacturer driver.

Comment: I checked and there are no manufacturer drivers provided for these drives, and the Windows drivers that are installed (provided by Microsoft) are definitely up to date.

Comment: I am very surprised that there are no drivers. This is poor support on Lite-on's part. I looked as well and came up empty. How about the other option I listed, removing them from hardware manager and forcing windows to redetect and reinstall etc? Any luck there?

Comment: I believe I tried that initially and it didn't make a difference. I unplugged one of the drives, booted, shut down, plugged it back in, and booted again, as I mentioned before, and it didn't change anything, either.

Comment: I'm wondering where the chat session went? Did you guys come up with anything? One thing I thought of is perhaps to sys prep the system, generalize it and reboot. Let the system go through all of the hardware redetection processes again as if its new out of the box. You shouldn't lose any data, I use this where I work to make a system image hardware independent. A quick google search should tell you how to sys prep, its quite easy in windows 7.

Comment: What we discussed was that perhaps when I went from IDE to RAID it confused Windows somehow and is no longer properly communicating with ATAPI devices as it should. What I'm going to try and do is run some system recovery tools using my Windows 7 disc, and if that doesn't help, try installing Windows fresh to see if it fixes the way Windows' HAL is setup. That may help give me some leads.

Comment: A sys prep probably would be the next step in that same effort. I'll take a look.

Comment: I found [this link on sysprepping](http://theitbros.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-%E2%80%93-start-to-finish). Does this describe the process that you were thinking of?

Comment: Well yes and no. That process is for making a completely unattended says prep with an XML file to answer the questions of time zone, computer name etc. all you want to do is run the sysprep file found in C:\windows\system32\sysprep, put the check in generalize and click restart, it will strip it back to barebones and reboot, forcing it to redetect all hardware again, you'll have to go through a short wizard to set the computer back up as if you just bought it, but I'm hoping it wil resolve the issue you're having.

Comment: I ran into an error when trying to run Sysprep. [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929828) describes it, and says to resolve it, I have to rebuild the Windows image. Does that mean reinstall Windows?

Comment: Aw that is awful. Each instance of windows only gets 3 rearms. I'm wondering if an OEM copy installed by a factory has this value at zero so you are unable to sysprep, at least easily. They talk about making an answer file with the no rearm option in there but in that case you might as well fresh install. =\

Comment: It's actually a copy that I bought through Microsoft online. I built the computer earlier this year... Though I do think that I recall seeing a way to rerun the upgrade installation path without uninstalling anything, and therefore losing your files. I may try doing that. In any case, I'll mark this as an answer since that would have been the ultimate solution (please update your answer accordingly).

Comment: Yeah it ends up being about time. Creating an answer file is a PITA and requires a large install of another software suite to get it done. There needs to be a better way. I'll update it to reflect the sysprep answer.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like it's a problem that Windows is having interfacing with your motherboard's chipset. Specifically, in speaking ATAPI to the CD Drive. Things I would recommend:

(**NOTE:** Please don't try more than one of these things at a time. It's never fun to solve something and not know exactly which step was the final piece to the puzzle. =) )

### Update Motherboard Chipset

Go to the manufacturer's website for your motherboard and download the latest chipset drivers. It will require a reboot, but shouldn't require any kind of pre-Windows boot media. You should be able to update from within Windows.

### Update storage controller

If your PC has a storage controller in it or a storage chipset (perhaps Matrox or Nvidia, as is the case in some consumer level PCs), update those chipsets / drivers.

### Update BIOS

It's *possible* that part of the problem is in the BIOS's presentation of the attachment. Consider
updating to the latest BIOS from your PC manufacturer for the model in question.

### Move the drive to a different SATA channel

If you have multple SATA ports, especially if you have ports that are on different controllers, move the optical drive to a new port on the motherboard.

### Curiosities

I would be interesting in knowing if your BIOS is in IDE or AHCI mode. I would *expect* it to be in IDE mode, but it's possible that it's in AHCI.

---

### EDIT 1

After finding out that the PC was switched from IDE to RAID/AHCI mode without a reinstall of Windows (and apparently it was something of an ordeal to get Windows to handle the change correctly) I believe that this might be the cause. Windows may be handling ATAPI communications slightly wrong now. I'm not sure yet what the solution would be. Perhaps a repair installation.

Comment: Also, I am using 2 hard drives in RAID0 so it's in RAID mode (AHCI, then, I would suspect), not IDE.

Comment: @sidran32 In my understanding, no, those things aren't necessarily OS agnostic. The chipsets still need to be interacted with by the OS, so the OS is still a variable factor. Perhaps Windows needs the hardware layer to have updated firmware for it to more properly interact with it. The Linux OS you tried may have been capable of interfacing with the chipset in its current state as opposed to Windows.

Comment: I just updated my BIOS and had a look through. There's three options for the SATA mode-IDE, RAID, and AHCI. I've had it in RAID mode all this time (because of my RAID0 setup). Would it be more desirable if it was in AHCI mode? By the way, the BIOS update did nothing, as well as the chipset driver update. Both my drives act the same and are on two different SATA channels, obviously. Same controller/

Comment: I doubt that would make a difference, however changing to AHCI will break your RAID set, so don't do that unless you're prepared for data loss. It will also require some changes to Windows. Search around for RAID-to-AHCI information such as: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/changing-from-raid-to-ahci/4c94f678-6bd1-48a6-b871-8872c841023a

Comment: If it won't make a difference then I wouldn't bother. I had to change from IDE to RAID when I set up RAID after the fact, which was a hassle. I don't want to do that again if I can help it. :)

Comment: Knowing that you changed from IDE to RAID intrigues me. I'm now suspicious that perhaps Windows is not properly interfacing with the ATAPI CD-Drive. Switching from IDE to RAID/AHCI could have caused issues with the Windows drivers for ATAPI.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2113/discussion-between-sidran32-and-wesleydavid)

Comment: I tried installing a fresh version of Windows after not being able to run a repair console. The fresh installation of Windows handles the disc burning properly. So it may be, as suggested, something wrong with how Windows is communicating with ATAPI devices.

Comment: @sidran32 That's unfortunate you weren't able to try the sys prep and had to go straight to a fresh install. Based on that, it may have worked. Oh well. Glad you got it fixed though.

Comment: @Paperlantern I actually am going to do a sysprep. I didn't want to leave it at the fresh install so I restored my system and will see if a sysprep will fix it. I just needed to get some new CD-Rs to test burning with before that. I'll get to it this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using different burning software? I'm a big fan of ImgBurn but too have found it often doesn't release the drive. Normally if I launch MakeMKV it will allow me to eject the disc (although it sounds like you already have a workaround).

Lee

Comment: I've used all sorts of burning software. It doesn't matter what I use, this always happens.